# RDF file for language synonyms

Tags: search-engine, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I am trying to build my own search engine and i want to add an ontology to it, so I want to add a **RDF** ontology that has all English language synonyms.

I already tried to search for RDF files from this website but i didn't found any think helpful

[DataSetRDFDumps](https://www.w3.org/wiki/DataSetRDFDumps)

I am trying to search for files or a way to make it my self but I can't find anything helpful, can any one help me??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to look for language-related RDF data is the [Linguistic Linked Open Data site](http://www.linguistic-lod.org/).

English language synonyms should be in WordNet which has an RDF version available:

- [WordNet RDF](http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/)